# @synthesize statement in the new Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In my Xcode project I do not need to @synthesize, in this case how can I set its value? Xcode error says that is an undeclared property.
Of course I cannot use self.someString in the setter and I do not have _someString.
So what to do?

MyClass.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, getter = getterMethodName, setter = setterMethodName:) NSString *someString;
```

Myclass.m

```
//SETTER
- (void) setSomeString:(NSString *) newString
{
  someString = newString;
}

- (NSString) someString
{
  return self.someString;
}
```

Comment: You assign like any other property: `someObject.someString = @"Hello";`

Comment: BTW - this has nothing to do with Xcode. This is a feature of the newer LLVM compiler that just happens to be used by default in newer versions of Xcode.

Comment: You need a colon after setterMethodName. Other than that, there's nothing wrong with the line. Where in the code do you get the error?

Comment: BTW, why are you defining getters and setters. That's a vary rare thing that you need to do. If you're just learning Obj-C, then you shouldn't be doing it at all yet. Learn the basics.

Comment: Can you show the place where XCode says it's undeclared? And there are still cases where you need to @synthesize (i.e. properties defined in a protocol)

Comment: @SteveWaddicor I don't use synthesize and if I remove it I cannot use _someString in the setter. That's my problem

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? And under Build Options, which compiler are you using? Make sure it is "Apple LLVM"

Comment: @Mr.Frank Sure you can. So why don't you show us your setter so we can see what the problem is.

Comment: Instead of `@property (nonatomic, strong, getter = getterMethodName, setter = setterMethodName:) NSString *someString;` why don't you just write `@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString* someString;`? You can still overwrite the setter as long as it follows the naming convention: `- (void)setSomeString: (NSString*) aString;`

Comment: @Mr.Frank Your code is using `someString` yet in your question and comments you talk about `_someString`. Change the code to use `_someString` and the problem is solved.

Comment: @SteveWaddicor I updated again. maybe is more clear

Comment: @codingFriend1 I updated again. maybe is more clear

Comment: @Mr.Frank please see my answer explaining the reason this is not working for you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand the question?

You no longer need the line

```
@synthesize someString = _someString;
```

You can still do these things :

```
self.someString = @"Hello";
```

or

```
_someString = @"goodbye";
```

You can even override the setter and getter

```
- (void)setSomeString:(NSString *)someString {
    if (_someString != someString) {
        _someString = someString;
    }
}
```

Literally the only change is that you don't need the synthesize line. Everything else is exactly the same.

Comment: I don't use synthesize and if I remove it I cannot use _someString in the setter. That's my problem.

Comment: See my answer, if you override BOTH the setter AND getter of your property then you DO have to synthesize it.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Every day's a school day!

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in that you no longer need to synthesize properties.

However, there is one caveat with this.

If you override BOTH the getter AND setter then YOU DO need to synthesize it.

Add this to your code...

```
@synthesize someString = _someString;
```

and change you getter and setter like this...

```
- (void)setSomeString:(NSString *)newString
{
  _someString = newString;
}

- (NSString *)someString
{
  return _someString;
}
```

Comment: No, don't synthesize it. Just create an iVar.

You're ARE declaring an iVar here. @synthesize is doing nothing else. And iVars belong in declarations.

Comment: Yes, you can complicate it that way if you want, but there is no need.

Comment: My way is simpler and more logical.  You are using a side effect of `@synthesize`, when the main purpose of `@synthesize` is both obsolete, and not used here.  And you do realise that your way isn't even shorter.

Comment: If you are not overriding both setter and getter you have access to _property. You don't need to create any ivar or anything. It just works. In this case creating an ivar of _property is not necessary and creating two references to the same data is just confusing.

Comment: See here... http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#Documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html especially the line saying "Avoid explicitly declaring public instance variables."

Comment: My method creates no more references to the same thing than yours.   @synthesize is no longer necessary. It's obsolete.  _someString is a private iVar that it used to create for it's own purposes.  If you are defining your own getter and setter, the reason _someString is not defined is because you are supposed to provide your own arrangements for storing the value.  My code does that.  You are using a side effect of an obsolete form, for no purpose.

Comment: You are doing something that Apple explicitly says not to do. The fact that they show how to @synthesize shows that synthesize clearly is not obsolete. In fact, the compiler DOES need synthesize, it just creates it for you at compile time.

Comment: I'd say both forms (`@synthesize` and explicit ivar) are perfectly acceptable.

Comment: In fact (and I'm not 100% on this), by only creating an iVar and NOT using synthesize I believe you are removing the memory management stuff from the ivar that you provided in the property (strong, weak, etc...).

Comment: That page was written when you still had to use @synthesize to auto-generate accessors.  The visibility point is valid, but that just means that is this is a public interface, the iVar belongs in a declaration in your .m file not your .h file.

Comment: THAT is a very good question. And on that basis, I defer to your solution.  With a weak property you'd probably have to declare the iVar as _weak too, and that's redundant.

Comment: The point is though that you do still need to synthesize. Just not explicitly. The ivar is still synthesised just at compile time. Unless you override both getter and setter.

Answer (score -1):

Ah, OK, I know what's going on here.

@synthesize was an instruction for the compiler to create a getter and a setter for you, and in order to be able to do it's work, it creates an instance variable _someString.

In recent versions of LLVM, @synthesize became optional. LLVM generates getter and setter for you, if you don't do it yourself.

But it only generates the _someString instance variable if it generates either a getter or a setter.

You are specifying both a getter and a setter, so LLVM isn't generating anything, including _someString.

If you declare both getter and setter, you have to define how the value is stored yourself.  If you want to have a _someString you have to declare it yourself.

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    NSString* _someString;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong, getter = getterMethodName, setter = setterMethodName:) NSString *someString;

@end
```

Comment: No, don't create an iVar. Just @synthesize it.

Comment: Answered below. Explicitly declaring an iVar is the best way.

Comment: Except it does exactly what Apple tells you not to do. Nice.

Comment: I aggree with Fogmeister ... This is bad style

Comment: "But it only generates the _someString instance variable if it generates either a getter or a setter." – this is simply not true. `@synthesize` does generate an ivar even if you provide your own setter *and* getter.

Comment: @omz Perhaps I wasn't clear. I meant in recent versions of LLVM, when you don't use `@sythesize`.

Comment: Ah, okay, I misunderstood that.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this answer. There is nothing wrong with declaring your own ivar for the property. @Fogmeister you keep saying that using `@synthesize` is better than creating your own ivar in this case. Why? All the `@synthesize` is going to do is create the same ivar as shown in this answer. What's the difference? Why is one bad and not the other? They give the same result.

Comment: This is wrong because ivars don't belong in the public interface anymore. Declared in a class extension or in the `@implementation`, your arguments hold, yes, but not here.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I completely agree that ivars shouldn't be in the .h. I admit I glossed over that detail in my comment since I was focused more on the "ivar bad - synthesize good" argument.